# Serilog or any loggers does not create file from task scheduler but creates from direct run

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, serilog

I have created a simple console application as below

```
string fileName =@"Logs\Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".xml";
        try
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
            file.Directory.Create();
            if (!file.Exists)
            {
                CreateNewLogFile(file);
            }
        }
```

Running the application from Visual Studio or direct exe from the folder generates log files.

But running through Task Scheduler no files were generated.

Full permission is granted for the log folders but no idea why files are not generated through Scheduler?

Comment: Have you tried the full path? E.g C:\User\Logs ?

Comment: No I haven't would it make any difference though?

Comment: It can make a difference. I also suggest you try the full path.

Comment: Given that the task scheduler is probably running under a service account, it's probably writing the file to somewhere different to your expectations. Provide a full path.

Comment: Are you swallowing errors? Written files do not just disappear. An error is thrown.

Comment: Thank you very much all. Yes it was the problem. I have given full path and now I see the file getting generated.

Comment: Where do you expect `Logs\Log` to be? On which hard drive? You have to pass absolute path, so you could go with e.g. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` + "\Logs\Log\abc.xml"

Answer (score 9):

When you run a console application the working folder is the same, but when you run a console application on a Schedule Task, the working folder is the system folder, so you maybe found your files on *C:\Windows\SysWOW64* or *C:\Windows\System32*.

Try to set the full path to save your files.